# How to return the status code in parseNetworkResponse in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

How can i return the status code of my api?

i know that the status code is generating in the parseNetworkResponse but i am using the parseNetworkResponse for the saving of cache, how can i still return the status code? is there other way to do this by using volley?

here is my code.

```
int status_code = 0;


    public void loadAnnouncement(){


        final Constant WebConfig = new Constant();

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, WebConfig.url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                    {

                        try {

                            JSONArray details = response.getJSONArray("data");


                            for (int i=0; i<details.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject object = details.getJSONObject(i);

                                announcementList.add(new AnnouncementModel(
                                        object.getInt("a"),
                                        object.getString("b"),
                                        object.getString("c"),
                                        object.getString("d"),
                                        object.getString("e"),
                                        object.getString("f")
                                ));

                                //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                                adapter = new AnnouncementAdapter(getActivity(), announcementList);
                                announcementRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){

            //This is for Headers If You Needed
            @Override
            public Map< String, String > getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map < String, String > params = new HashMap< String, String >();
                params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                params.put("X-API-KEY", WebConfig.test);
                params.put("Authorization", WebConfig.test1);
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                try {
                    Cache.Entry cacheEntry = HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response);
                    if (cacheEntry == null) {
                        cacheEntry = new Cache.Entry();
                    }
                    final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
                    final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
                    final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;
                    cacheEntry.data = response.data;
                    cacheEntry.softTtl = softExpire;
                    cacheEntry.ttl = ttl;
                    String headerValue;
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Date");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    headerValue = response.headers.get("Last-Modified");
                    if (headerValue != null) {
                        cacheEntry.lastModified = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
                    }
                    cacheEntry.responseHeaders = response.headers;
                    final String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString), cacheEntry);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
                super.deliverResponse(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
                super.deliverError(error);
            }

            @Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
            }
        };

        queue.add(getRequest);
    }
```

this is working, but i still need to return the status_code of it.

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: In parseNetworkResponse method you can get the response code, response.statusCode;

Comment: Hi @MridulSKumar yes i know, but how can i implement through my parseNetworkResponse? considering that i am returning the cache on it?

Comment: I think if you return the NetworkResponse as well you can get the status code from it